# How do I save all the comments I've made on YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube

I'd like to be able to see all of them (Google search doesn't show them all)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to view **all** of your YouTube comments.

You can view your recent comments (I believe this is the last 3 or 4 days) by using the Comment Search

[http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=[YOUR_YOUTUBE_USERNAME]](http://www.youtube.com/comment_search?username=%5BYOUR_YOUTUBE_USERNAME%5D)

Comment: Does not work anymore... 404